# Height that fits, not 100%

Tags: css, html

Setting the height to 100% on my web page is messing things up.  The footer is not staying on the main page, it's going past the main viewable area.... how do I prevent this from happening so that it stays on the bottom of the page?

see example: [URL_REMOVED]

Comment: Checkout the all-css StickyFooter: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: you know you'll get much better results if you improve you're question. Add some code maybe.

Comment: question improved... @Jared: I've basically already done that... it stays at the bottom, but it's like the floated elements on the page are pushing it down further or something

Comment: I know StickyFooter works when applied correctly. It's hard for me to tell what you've done, as you didn't post the relevant markup and css in your question, and I don't feel like digging through your site for the relevant code to find your problem.

Comment: Post some code or construct a simple demo in a jsFiddle.  Perhaps while constructing your jsFiddle, you'll discover the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the footer inside the `<div id="bdy"></div>` and positioning it on the bottom.
Since the `#bdy` has `min-height: 100%`, it pushes the footer down.

If you place the footer inside the `#bdy`, give it the style `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`.

**UPDATE:**

Ah, that is because the `position: absolute;` on the footer makes the instruction `bottom: 0;` stick it to the closest ancestor which does have not `position: static`(which is default). You can fix the issue by applying `position: relative;` to `#bdy`.

Comment: Unfortunately that messes things up when I end up scrolling: http://www.dealclippings.com/privacy/